# How does one patch a hole in a smooth stucco exterior?

Tags: siding, stucco, hole-repair

My house has this nice smooth stucco siding. There is a hole (not pictured) that is no longer needed. It’s about 3/4” diameter. What’s the best way to patch that up?

[image: siding]
[image: closeup]

Answer (score 1):

Try [Stucco Patch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071WLDS58)

Put it on with a putty knife. Fill the hole, then skim over with another thin layer.

You didn't give a pic of your finish, so I can't say exactly how to final finish.  For Sand texture wipe it with a wet paint brush. For a smoother surface   use a damp sponge. Wetting the putty knife and wiping can give an even smoother surface, but this is rare for stucco.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a picture. Let me know if you need a different picture.

Comment: I cannot tell a type of texture from that pic.  Does the surface feel like sandpaper?  Can you get a close up of the area that needs to be patched?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's too far away. The surface is very smooth. I wouldn't describe it as sandpaper. I added another photo.

Comment: It looks like the wet putty knife is the first thing to try.